# Kickstart CentOS 6 prompting for TCP/IP with network set to DHCP

Tags: centos6, kickstart

I am trying to stop my kickstart CentOS install prompting me for TCP/IP information. After I click through this prompt (keeping IPv4 and IPv6 to their defaults) the installation continues and completes just fine. Below is my kickstart file:

```
# Andy's super awesome VM kickstart file

install
url --url=http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/os/x86_64
lang en_US.UTF-8
keyboard us
text
%include /tmp/network.ks
rootpw  --iscrypted $6$RA8DyrNTsVJkGIgY$ohZ62HHiOjNnn1yDMZlIu3lQ63D3plGPcbVZtPKE8Oq6Z.IGUgN.kNLkxs/ZymZuluRDWsW2eey5zLOl2G3mp.
firewall --service=ssh
authconfig --enableshadow --passalgo=sha512
selinux --disabled
timezone America/Los_Angeles
bootloader --location=mbr --driveorder=vda --append="crashkernel=auto rhgb quiet"
# The following is the partition information you requested
# Note that any partitions you deleted are not expressed
# here so unless you clear all partitions first, this is
# not guaranteed to work
zerombr
clearpart --all --drives=vda --initlabel

part /boot --fstype=ext4 --size=500
part pv.253002 --grow --size=1
volgroup vg1 --pesize=4096 pv.253002
logvol / --fstype=ext4 --name=lv_root --vgname=vg1 --grow --size=1024 --maxsize=51200
logvol swap --name=lv_swap --vgname=vg1 --grow --size=4032 --maxsize=4032

repo --name="CentOS"  --baseurl=http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/os/x86_64 --cost=100
repo --name="Puppet Labs Products"  --baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/products/x86_64
repo --name="Puppet Labs Dependencies"  --baseurl=http://yum.puppetlabs.com/el/6/dependencies/x86_64
repo --name="EyeFi"  --baseurl=http://flexo.eye.fi/6/eye-fi-api

%packages
@core
@server-policy
puppet
facter
%end

%pre --erroronfail
#!/bin/bash
for x in `cat /proc/cmdline`; do
        case $x in SERVERNAME*)
                eval $x
                echo "network --onboot yes --device eth0 --bootproto dhcp --hostname ${SERVERNAME}.eye.fi" > /tmp/network.ks
                ;;
        esac;
done
%end

%post
puppet agent --waitforcert 10 --onetime --no-daemon --pluginsync --server puppet.eye.fi
%end

reboot
```

My kernel arguments are in this following virt-install command that I use to start the install:

`virt-install -n zabbix -r 2048 --vcpus=2 -l http://mirrors.kernel.org/centos/6/os/x86_64 --disk /dev/vg_inf1/zabbix --network bridge=br85 --initrd-inject=/home/ashinn/vm_kickstart --extra-args "ks=file:/vm_kickstart SERVERNAME=zabbix" --autostart`

During the install, I can pull up a console on the second terminal and verify the contents of `/tmp/network.ks` are:

`network --onboot=yes --bootproto=dhcp --ipv6=auto --hostname=jenkins2.mydomain.com`

Why might Anaconda be prompting for the TCP/IP settings when they are already set to DHCP?

Comment: Can you check if the settings in /tmp/network.ks are correct?

Comment: I updated the question to reflect the contents of /tmp/network.ks

Answer (score 1):

The Configure TCP/IP prompt will always display if DHCP fails for any reason. Try specifying the specific ethernet interface you want to use with --device=ethX.

I ran into this issue on a machine that was set up to DHCP from eth2 and my standard kickstart config used eth0.